# Handling PayPal IPNs received in unexpected time order

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When a user placed an order, the IPN listener would receive a notification from PayPal with the `payment_status='Completed'`. Later, for some reasons, if we had to refund to the user, PayPal would send a notification to the listener with `payment_status='Refunded'` or `payment_status='Reversed'`.

Since the internet is not always reliable, is this possible for the IPN listener to receive these two IPNs in the wrong order? In other words, the IPN listener received the `Refunded` notification before the `Completed` notification.

If yes, what are the typical approaches to handle such case?

Comment: Why would you refund to the user before you had the IPN that confirmed the payment was complete? Think about your business here.

Comment: @EJP Yes, we would not. But if PayPal ensures that the `Refunded` notification (if any) is sent after the `Completed` notification, we don't have to implement unnecessary logic in the codes to handle such case.